# Why is the style on a rect not being applied?

Tags: css, svg

I have a `<rect>` that has a style that is different from its group `<g>`. The `cw` style is not being applied to Child 3.

```css
path {
  fill:none;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-opacity: 1;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-linecap: round;
}

g.spinoff path,
path.spinoff { stroke: #0000ff; }

rect {
  paint-order: stroke;
  stroke: #666666;
  stroke-width: 4;
  stroke-opacity: 1;
  fill-opacity: 1;
  fill: #ffffff;
}

g.dc rect { fill: #66ccff; }
rect.cw { fill: #99ff99; }

text  {
  fill: #000000;
  font-family: arial, roboto, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-style: italic;
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-align: center;
  text-anchor: start;
  dominant-baseline: middle;
}
```

```xml
<svg viewBox="0 0 101 198" width="101" height="198">
  <g transform="translate(5,5)">
    <g id="Top_box_franchise" transform="translate(0,0)" class="dc">
      <title id="Top_box_franchise_title">Top box</title>
      <g class="spinoff" id="Top_box_spinoff_group" transform="translate(13)">
        <title id="Top_box_spinoff_group_title">The Top box spinoffs</title>
        <path d="m 0,  30 v 24 h 15" id="Top_box_to_Child_1" />
        <path d="m 0,  54 v 40 h 15" id="Top_box_to_Child_2" />
        <path d="m 0,  94 v 40 h 15" id="Top_box_to_Child_3" />
        <path d="m 0, 134 v 40 h 15" id="Top_box_to_Child_4" />
      </g>
      <g id="Top_box" transform="translate(0,0)">
        <title id="Top_box_title">Top box</title>
        <rect id="Top_box_box" x="0" y="0" width="69" height="28" />
        <text id="Top_box_text" x="6" y="14">Top box</text>
      </g>
      <g id="Child_1" transform="translate(30,40)">
        <title id="Child_1_title">Child 1</title>
        <rect id="Child_1_box" x="0" y="0" width="61" height="28" />
        <text id="Child_1_text" x="6" y="14">Child 1</text>
      </g>
      <g id="Child_2" transform="translate(30,80)">
        <title id="Child_2_title">Child 2</title>
        <rect id="Child_2_box" x="0" y="0" width="62" height="28" />
        <text id="Child_2_text" x="6" y="14">Child 2</text>
      </g>
      <g id="Child_3" transform="translate(30,120)">
        <title id="Child_3_title">Child 3</title>
        <rect id="Child_3_box" x="0" y="0" width="62" height="28" class="cw" />
        <text id="Child_3_text" x="6" y="14">Child 3</text>
      </g>
      <g id="Child_4" transform="translate(30,160)">
        <title id="Child_4_title">Child 4</title>
        <rect id="Child_4_box" x="0" y="0" width="62" height="28" />
        <text id="Child_4_text" x="6" y="14">Child 4</text>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

A live version is [here](https://codepen.io/LadyAleena/pen/KKdvdZQ?editors=1100).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a specificity issue... use `g rect.cw` .. note the space.